# Can't pass time as argument to function

Tags: javascript

I need to pass time in colon format as an argument

```
var carSlider = new Slider(
    'car_slider',
    {
        minVal:   "11:30",
        maxVal:   500,
        onChange: function() { console.log(arguments); }
    }
);
```

I am using the above code to pass

But then it shows the following error

SyntaxError: missing } after property list

```
...ider('bus_depart_slider',{minVal:11:30,maxVal:500,onChange: function() {console....
```

Comment: that is not php, that is js, use the right tag mate :)

Comment: The code you posted for `car_slider` looks right (syntaxically speaking). Show us the full code for `bus_depart_slider` (where you actually get an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all, albeit like most error messages half the battle is deciphering what it means!

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list

When it refers to a "property list" what it usually means is an object literal where the property list is the list of properties contained in that object literal

```
var myObjLiteral = {
      prop: "foo"
};
```

In the above code if I omitted the closing `}` I would get the above error

```
var myObjLiteral = {
      prop: "foo"

// error here - SyntaxError: missing } after property list

var nextLine = "bar"
```

Now, with reference to your code, you are passing 2 parameters to `Slider` - the first is a string, the second is an object literal:

```
var carSlider = new Slider(
    'car_slider', // argument 1 (string)
    {
        minVal:   "11:30",
        maxVal:   500,
        onChange: function() { console.log(arguments); }
    } // argument 2 (object literal)
);
```

If you omit the closing braces, you will see the error described

```
var carSlider = new Slider(
    'car_slider', 
    {
        minVal:   "11:30",
        maxVal:   500,
        onChange: function() { console.log(arguments); }

    // SyntaxError: missing } after property list        

);
```

Another way to get this error message is passing a string variable without wrapping it in quotes - the javascript interpreter will probably try to parse what you intended as a string instead as a variable or function declaration - the end result is usually that it *thinks* you've forgotten a closing `}` as per the above example.

```
var carSlider = new Slider(
    'car_slider', 
    {
        minVal:   11:30, // <-- look here
        maxVal:   500,
        onChange: function() { console.log(arguments); }
    } 
);
```

In the above example, instead of passing the string `"11:30"` ive forgotten the quotes. Javascript will try to evaluate `11:30` as if its a declaration. The `:` has a specific meaning in javascript syntax (as part of a ternary operator) yet the rest of it does not make sense in the context it is placed.

Im not sure which of these 2 mistakes you've made, but one of them will be the cause.